# JS Regex to replace all html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

i have spent a while researching this and cant find a solution, i am looking for a method to remove all html tags from a string and if img tags appear, then replace them with just the src attribute, sorry for little information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might be what you need:

```js
var str = "<b>TEST</b> <p><img src='path.png' /> boom <span>sss</span></p>";

var text = $(str).find('img').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).end().text();

alert(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this code does answer my question so I'll accept as answer, however it does not work in my code, I'll have to adjust this code to suit my needs.

Comment: Could you please update your answer so others may see:
    $("<div>" + str + "</div>").find('img').replaceWith(function() {

Comment: If you're looking for a code answer, you should ask for code not a regex.

Answer (score 2):

First do a regex replace, replacing this

`<img.+?src="(.+?)".*?>`

with this `\1`.  That will replace the whole img tags with just the contents of the src attribute.

Then do the replacement for all the rest of the tags using this

`<.+?>`

and replace with nothing/blank.

Comment: Wouldn't `<?.+>` be greedy and therefore match the entire string `<b>this is my text</b>` rather than just `<b>` and `</b>`?

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct!  I had a typo.  It should have read `<.+?>`.  Thanks for pointing that out.  :)